# SharePoint 2007 - Current Timer jobs?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, timer-jobs

How to find the currently running SharePoint 2007 Timer jobs using STSADM?

Comment: Uhm, why sharepoint-designer tag here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not sure if you can do that with default
  stsadm commands, but possible if you [write a
  custom stsadm command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417382.aspx).
- [Someone already wrote a stsadm command](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/09/enumerate-timer-job-definitions.html) where
  you can enumerate job definitions
  with stsadm. Just download and
  install.
- There is also [SharePoint
  Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/spm) available which shows
  that information and many other. It
  is a very good tool that I can
  recommend for SharePoint developers
  and Administrators.